# Django Search Bar Function Not Yielding Results

Tags: python, django

I have a table that is shown in my django app that I am trying to filter with a search bar. I am not receiving any errors, but whenever I search anything (id, name, etc) no data pops up.

search.html:

```
{% extends "polls/stakeholders.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for stakeholder in all_search_results %}
<h3>{{stakeholder.employee}}</h3>
<p>{{stakeholder.description}}</p>
    {% empty %}
<h2>No results found</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

stakeholders.html (table and search bar portion):

```
           <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'polls:search' %}">
               <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="search">
               <button class="btn btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"> Search </button>
           </form>
           <br>
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:90% ">
               <thead>
                   <tr style="font-family: Graphik Black; font-size: 14px">
                       <th scope="col">#</th>
                       <th scope="col">Employee</th>
                       <th scope="col">Stakeholder Group</th>
                       <th scope="col">Quadrant</th>
                       <th scope="col">Description</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   {% for stakeholder in stakeholder_list %}
                   <tr style="font-family: Graphik;font-size: 12px">
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.id }}</td>
                       <td style="font-size: 15px">{{ stakeholder.employee }}</td>
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_group }}</td>
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.stakeholder_quadrant }}</td>
                       <td>{{ stakeholder.description }}</td>
                       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm badge-pill" style="font-size: 11px; width:60px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new">Edit</button></td>
                   </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

urls.py

```
    path('results/', views.SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
```

views.py (currently filters by id, but i've already tried the other fields)

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = Stakeholder
    template_name = 'polls/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if query:
            postresult = Stakeholder.objects.filter(id__contains=query)
            result = postresult
        else:
            result = None
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you dont get any results because  self.request.GET.get('search') returns a string and id is an integer (by default) or uuid in special cases.

so one solution might be to use int(query) but on the other hand it's a bit odd to filter for db ids since the use should never care about db ids. It might help to use .lower().strip() on search strings to get more consisten results. Search quickly gets complex, especially full text search, i recommend the django docs as a starting point.

[Django Documentation on search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/search/)

I would recommend to alway add an order_by('field') statement to queries that go to the frontend,otherwise it is possible to get different results each time you query.  keep in mind to use an index on the field that you use in order by, if not your query will get very slow when you have many objects.